# Compatible DDR3 memory causes mainboard to beep 5 times

Tags: motherboard, ddr

I got that old "office" PC lounging around which didn't have RAM modules. So I checked the specs and bought some new memory (2x Patriot DIMM 4 GB DDR3-1333). That's PC3 10600 or 1333 MHz DDR3 RAM. The [mainboard (a HP 3048h)](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c03885123) specs give me a thumbs-up.

But now when booting I only hear 5 beeps, according to [HP](https://support.hp.com/bg-en/document/c02222922) that indicates something different from a memory error.

Since I got the same (as in same model and same mainboard) PC working with other PC3 10600 RAM I'm now wondering what went wrong.

The memory *working* in both PCs/with the same mainboard:

**1GB 1RX8 PC3-10600U-9-10-A0** fromMicron Tech (with a HP sticker on the back of the module)

The memory *not working & beeping* in both PCs/with the same mainboard:

**4GB PC3-10600-9-9-9** [see here](https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/20c502_fbb6cc6a408a4ed5874786d94f161246.pdf)

- Is there a difference in PC3-10600 and 10600U?
- Might the different timings be the cause for incompatibility (the mainboard specs say nothing about (in)compatible timings)?

I returned both memory modules to the dealer, they checked, didn't find anything and sent the exact modules back to me.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:
Thanks @Ramhound for the hint. The sticker of the old memory says PC3-10600**U**, the new one is a PC3-10600 but the manufacturers website states that this one is also *Non-ECC Unbuffered*.

Comment: The mainboard specs also say "Supports 1 GB, 2 GB, 4 GB and 8 GB DIMMs"

Comment: Based on the part number, you purchased incompatible memory, the U in the part number is significant in a case like this.

Comment: Your question did not use consisting part numbers, I based my conclusion, on the pet numbers in the single question in the body of your question.  I would make sure you provided the exact part numbers.

Comment: Are you getting a load up screen when you turn on the computer once you have installed the memory? If not there is the possibility you have a bad slot.

Comment: Just beeping and a black screen. All slots work fine with the memory from the other PC.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound for the hint. The sticker of the old memory says PC3-10600U, the new one is a PC3-10600 but the manufacturers website states that this one is also Non-ECC Unbuffered.

Comment: @entenbein - If your existing memory is ECC memory, attempting to use non-ECC memory, would explain the issue you have.

Comment: @Ramhound - The old memory is also non-ECC (8 black modules) just as the new one. And by the way, the required voltage is also the same.